# CSS3 animation:element moved to its initial position after @keyframes actions

Tags: animation, css, position, element

CSS3 animation reverts element to its initial position.

`div` is moved bottom direction,than it takes its initial position.

Is it intended behavior?
Could it stay on last position?

see,please, live demo: [fiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2Fhf/15/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your css rues as...

```
-vendor-animation: mymove 1s 1 forwards;
```

It's the shorthand way of stating:

```
-ventor-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

That prevents your animation from resetting to the beggining